# Angular 2 checkbox filtering

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-pipe, array-filter

i want to filter multiple checkboxes with Angular 2 and achieve something like [THIS](https://codepen.io/arturparkhisenko/pen/pJPrRr) .
The problem is that the app is not working when i check 2 different checkboxes.

**App.Component.html**

```
    <div  *ngFor="let s of cpuName">
      <input  type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="s.checked" (click)="updateFilter(s)"  >{{s.name}}
    </div>

    <div  *ngFor="let n of cpuCode">
      <input  type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="n.checked" (click)="updateFilter(n)"  >{{n.name}}
    </div>

  <ul>
      <div *ngFor="let a of allCpu | filterPipe: filterArr">
          ID: {{a.id}}, Name: {{a.name}}, Code: {{a.code}}
      </div>
  </ul>
```

**App.Component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  filterArr = [];
  cpuName = [{checked:false,name:'Intel'},{checked:false,name:'AMD'}]
  cpuCode =[{checked:false,name:'i5'},{checked:false,name:'i7'},{checked:false,name:'ryzen7'}]
  name:string;

  allCpu = [
    {id:1, name:'Intel', code:'i5'},
    {id:2, name:'Intel', code:'i5'},
    {id:3, name:'AMD', code:'ryzen7'},
    {id:4, name:'Intel', code:'i7'},
    {id:5, name:'AMD', code:'ryzen7'},
    {id:6, name:'Intel', code:'i7'}
  ]


  updateFilter(option) {
    if(!option.checked) {
      this.filterArr.push(option.name);
      console.log(this.filterArr);
    }
    else {
      let index = this.filterArr.indexOf(option.name);
      this.filterArr.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

**Pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filterPipe',
    pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any[]): any {
        return  value.filter(item => {
            return args.length ? args.indexOf(item.name) != -1 : value;
        })
    }
}
```

This is the [Final Output](http://expensive-scissors.surge.sh)

[GITHUB PROJECT](https://github.com/NikosDev/angular-forms)

Comment: The i5, i7 are code in your allCpu, you need to modify your pipe when iterate item check either name or code

Answer (score 0):

You're almost get it work.

The i5, i7 are code in your allCpu, you need to modify your pipe when iterate item check either name or code

`item` has 2 properties: name and code.

Your Intel and AMD filters work because you check whether args contains the item name.

```
 transform(value: any, args?: any[]): any {
   let result = value.filter( item => args.indexOf(item.name) > -1);
   result = value.filter(item => args.indexOf(item.code) > -1);
   return result;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately the result is not what i expect. If i check AMD and i7 i expect to see null because there is not any AMD cpu with i7, but i see this (https://imgur.com/8pfsUMv). This is my github repository in case you want to clone(https://github.com/NikosDev/angular-forms)

Comment: @DevelopmentFlow I see. It's because use "||" operator, it returns true either name or code in your filterArr. You can modify to filter name first then filter code for the name filtered array